# Populate a PeoplePicker with current user in SharePoint Hosted Add-in

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, sharepoint-online, office365-apps

Does anyone have some "boilerplate" code that works in JavaScript that will pull back the current user and their manager from SharePoint User Profile?  I would prefer using a Rest API but anything that gets me my data would be wonderful.

I want to utilize the User Profile in an Office 365 SharePoint Hosted Add-in to populate the 3 People Picker controls (Requestor, Payee and Manager) when the user firsts loads the page.  All of these people can be retrieved from the current user's profile information in our SharePoint tenant but every time I try and get that information I get a forbidden or permission problem.  I am a SharePoint Administrator on our site and have added read permissions set in the AppManifest.xml in the application.

```js
<AppPermissionRequests>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/tenant" Right="Read" />
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

I have given the JavaScript code and html below that makes the People Picker work in an html page but to run it you will need to create a SharePoint Hosted Add-in with jQuery and Bootstrap.  Note: This is not an ASP.Net page but an html page. 
 Thank you in advance for any help with this problem.

```js
// Run your custom code when the DOM is ready.
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Specify the unique ID of the DOM element where the
    // picker will render.
    initializePeoplePicker('requestorDiv');
    initializePeoplePicker('payeeDiv');
    initializePeoplePicker('managerDiv');
});

// Render and initialize the client-side People Picker.
function initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId) {

    // Create a schema to store picker properties, and set the properties.
    var schema = {};
    schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
    schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = true;
    schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
    schema['Width'] = '280px';

    // Render and initialize the picker. 
    // Pass the ID of the DOM element that contains the picker, an array of initial
    // PickerEntity objects to set the picker value, and a schema that defines
    // picker properties.
    this.SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);
}

// Query the picker for user information.
function getUserInfo(person) {

    // Get the people picker object from the page.
    var peoplePicker = null;
    switch (person.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'requestor':
            peoplePicker = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.requestorDiv_TopSpan;
            break;
        case 'payee':
            peoplePicker = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.payeeDiv_TopSpan;
            break;
        case 'manager':
            peoplePicker = this.SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.managerDiv_TopSpan;
            break;
    }

    // Get information about all users.
    var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();

    //start new process
    var userInfo = '';
    var fullName = "";
    var email = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        var firstName = "";
        var middleInitial = "";
        var lastName = "";
        var rawName = user['DisplayText'];
        var count = rawName.split(' ').length;
        rawName = rawName.split(' ');
        firstName = rawName[1];
        lastName = rawName[0];
        fullName = firstName + " " + lastName;
        if (count == 3) {
            middleInitial = rawName[2];
            fullName = firstName + " " + middleInitial + " " + lastName;
        }
        for (var userProperty in user) {
            userInfo += userProperty + ':  ' + user[userProperty] + '<br>';
            if (userProperty == 'Description') {
                email = user[userProperty].toLowerCase();
            }
        }
    }

    $('#resolvedUsers').html(userInfo);
    $('#email').html(email);
    $('#fullName').html(fullName);
    $('#username').html(fullName);
    $('#usertype').html(person);
    switch (person.toLowerCase()) {
        case 'requestor':
            $('#input-requestor').val(fullName);
            $('#requestorEmail').text(email)
            break;
        case 'payee':
            $('#input-payee').val(fullName);
            $('#payeeEmail').text(email)
            break;
        case 'manager':
            $('#input-manager').val(fullName);
            $('#managerEmail').text(email)
            break;
    }
    // Get user keys.
    var keys = peoplePicker.GetAllUserKeys();
    $('#userKeys').html(keys);

    // Get the first user's ID by using the login name.
    getUserId(users[0].Key);

}

// Get the user ID.
function getUserId(loginName) {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    this.user = context.get_web().ensureUser(loginName);
    context.load(this.user);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(null, ensureUserSuccess),
        Function.createDelegate(null, onFail)
    );
}

function ensureUserSuccess() {
    $('#userId').html(this.user.get_id());
}

function onFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Query failed. Error: ' + args.get_message());
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title></title>
    <link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/15/1033/styles/Themable/corev15.css" />
    <style>
        .modal-title{
            font-weight: bold;
            font-size: large;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="container-fluid">
    <br />
    <form class="form">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2 text-left"><label for="input-requestor" class="topic">Requestor:&nbsp;<i class="text-danger"><strong>*</strong></i>&nbsp;</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-left"><label for="input-payee" class="topic">Payee:&nbsp;<i class="text-danger"><strong>*</strong></i>&nbsp;</label></div>
            <div class="col-md-2 text-left"><label for="input-manager" class="topic">Manager:&nbsp;<i class="text-danger"><strong>*</strong></i>&nbsp;</label></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Person filling out form" id="input-requestor" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#peopleModal" data-person="Requestor">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        </a>
                    </span>
                    <input id="requestorEmail" hidden="hidden" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Person getting reimbursement" id="input-payee">
                    <span class="input-group-btn" title="Get payee">
                        <a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#peopleModal" data-person="Payee"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> </a>
                    </span>
                    <input id="payeeEmail" hidden="hidden" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly" placeholder="Approving manager" id="input-manager">
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <a class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#peopleModal" data-person="Manager"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> </a>
                    </span>
                    <input id="managerEmail" hidden="hidden" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--end of row one-->

    </form>

    <div class="modal fade" id="peopleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="peopleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h3 class="modal-title" id="peopleModalLabel">New message</h3>
                    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form>
                        <div id="requestorDiv"></div>
                        <div id="payeeDiv"></div>
                        <div id="managerDiv"></div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button id="okModalButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="../Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/tether.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/1033/initstrings.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/1033/strings.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.UI.Controls.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/clienttemplates.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/clientforms.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/autofill.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.init.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.ui.dialog.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/core.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.Core.JS"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/App.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#peopleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
                var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
                var recipient = button.data('person'); // Extract info from data-* attributes
                // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
                // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
                var modal = $(this);
                switch (recipient.toLowerCase()) {
                    case 'requestor':
                        $("#requestorDiv").show();
                        $("#payeeDiv").hide();
                        $("#managerDiv").hide();
                        break;
                    case 'payee':
                        $("#requestorDiv").hide();
                        $("#payeeDiv").show();
                        $("#managerDiv").hide();
                        break;
                    case 'manager':
                        $("#requestorDiv").hide();
                        $("#payeeDiv").hide();
                        $("#managerDiv").show();
                        break;
                }
                modal.find('.modal-title').text('Find ' + recipient + ' using people picker box below');
                modal.find('#okModalButton').click(function () { getUserInfo(recipient) });

            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set people control default value by below script. **peoplePickerDiv** matches the control id `<div id="peoplePickerDiv"></div>`

```
SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan.AddUserKeys(user.get_email());
```

My test project:

```
<%-- The following 4 lines are ASP.NET directives needed when using SharePoint components --%>

<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage, Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>

<%-- The markup and script in the following Content element will be placed in the <head> of the page --%>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.js" runat="server" OnDemand="true" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <meta name="WebPartPageExpansion" content="full" />

    <!-- Add your CSS styles to the following file -->
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Content/App.css" />

    <!-- Add your JavaScript to the following file -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/App.js"></script>
</asp:Content>

<%-- The markup in the following Content element will be placed in the TitleArea of the page --%>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server">
    Page Title
</asp:Content>

<%-- The markup and script in the following Content element will be placed in the <body> of the page --%>
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clienttemplates.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clientforms.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="clientpeoplepicker.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="autofill.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.runtime.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <SharePoint:ScriptLink name="sp.core.js" runat="server" LoadAfterUI="true" Localizable="false" />
    <div id="peoplePickerDiv"></div>
    <div>
        <br/>
        <input type="button" value="Get User Info" onclick="getUserInfo()"></input>
        <br/>
        <h1>User info:</h1>
        <p id="resolvedUsers"></p>
        <h1>User keys:</h1>
        <p id="userKeys"></p> 
        <h1>User ID:</h1>
        <p id="userId"></p>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

App.js

```
'use strict';

ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(initializePage, "sp.js");

function initializePage()
{
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();

    // This code runs when the DOM is ready and creates a context object which is needed to use the SharePoint object model
    $(document).ready(function () {
        getUserName();
    });

    // This function prepares, loads, and then executes a SharePoint query to get the current users information
    function getUserName() {
        context.load(user);
        context.executeQueryAsync(onGetUserNameSuccess, onGetUserNameFail);
    }

    // This function is executed if the above call is successful
    // It replaces the contents of the 'message' element with the user name
    function onGetUserNameSuccess() {
        SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan.AddUserKeys(user.get_email());        

    }

    // This function is executed if the above call fails
    function onGetUserNameFail(sender, args) {
        alert('Failed to get user name. Error:' + args.get_message());
    }
}

// Run your custom code when the DOM is ready.
$(document).ready(function () {

    // Specify the unique ID of the DOM element where the
    // picker will render.
    initializePeoplePicker('peoplePickerDiv');
});

// Render and initialize the client-side People Picker.
function initializePeoplePicker(peoplePickerElementId) {

    // Create a schema to store picker properties, and set the properties.
    var schema = {};
    schema['PrincipalAccountType'] = 'User,DL,SecGroup,SPGroup';
    schema['SearchPrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['ResolvePrincipalSource'] = 15;
    schema['AllowMultipleValues'] = true;
    schema['MaximumEntitySuggestions'] = 50;
    schema['Width'] = '280px';

    // Render and initialize the picker. 
    // Pass the ID of the DOM element that contains the picker, an array of initial
    // PickerEntity objects to set the picker value, and a schema that defines
    // picker properties.
    SPClientPeoplePicker_InitStandaloneControlWrapper(peoplePickerElementId, null, schema);
}

// Query the picker for user information.
function getUserInfo() {

    // Get the people picker object from the page.
    var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict.peoplePickerDiv_TopSpan;

    // Get information about all users.
    var users = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
    var userInfo = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
        var user = users[i];
        for (var userProperty in user) {
            userInfo += userProperty + ':  ' + user[userProperty] + '<br>';
        }
    }
    $('#resolvedUsers').html(userInfo);

    // Get user keys.
    var keys = peoplePicker.GetAllUserKeys();
    $('#userKeys').html(keys);

    // Get the first user's ID by using the login name.
    getUserId(users[0].Key);
}

// Get the user ID.
function getUserId(loginName) {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var user = context.get_web().ensureUser(loginName);
    context.load(user);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
         function () {
             $('#userId').html(user.get_id());
         },
         function onFail(sender, args) {
             alert('Query failed. Error: ' + args.get_message());
         }
    );
}
```